# ¿Cómo hacer para almacenar archivos .doc o .pdf seleccionados por el usuario con Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Hace tiempo que trabajo con python y tkinter con el que he logrado varias cosas, pero ahora estoy empezando con la idea de programar web apps pero estoy medio perdido en como funcionan las cosas con intenet de pir medio.

Estoy intentando armar una aplicación que permite a los usuarios guardar archivos y registra usuario y fecha. En un principio lo pensé para guardarlos en una tabla sqlite3 como blob que podría funcionar pero me trabé en que no encuentro la forma que el usuario abra un cuadro de diálogo para elegir el archivo de su computadora . Con solo el path absoluto del archivo podría continuar. Lo que necesitaría sería una función similar a la *askopenfilename* de **tkinter** por lo que no pude avanzar mas en ese enfoque.

Si encontré una forma de abrir un diálogo para elegir un archivo y guardarlo donde uno lo indique. Eso logré que funcione bien pero corriendo flask en mi localhost y eligiendo archivos de mi computadora y guardándolos en misma computadora con el path absoluto como se muestra en el link siguiente:
https://pythonise.com/series/learning-flask/flask-uploading-files
Ahora, no creo que eso lo pueda hacer cuando suba mi app a un host. No logré encontrar como hacer para almacenar archivos.

En concreto quería saber si existe una forma de obtener el path de un archivo usando flask y html o si alguien me puede indicar cómo se maneja el almacenamiento de archivos que uno quiere almacenar en un host.

Comment: podrías compartir el código que no te funciona ?

Answer (score 0):

Al final logré resolverlo. Pongo el código que me funcionó:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import sqlite3
import os
import datetime
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import (StringField, BooleanField, DateTimeField,
                     RadioField,SelectField,TextField,
                     TextAreaField,SubmitField)


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "hola"
con = sqlite3.connect("base.db") #conecto a la base
c = con.cursor() #defino el cursor
#c.execute("DROP TABLE Archivos")
c.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists Archivos (Nombre TEXT, Fecha TEXT, Archivo BOLB)") #Crea la tabla
con.commit()
con.close()


@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        fecha = datetime.date.today()
        con = sqlite3.connect("base.db") #conecto a la base
        c = con.cursor() #defino el cursor
        c.execute("INSERT INTO Archivos VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (f.filename, fecha, f.read()))
        con.commit()
        con.close()
        return 'file uploaded successfully'
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route("/download", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def download():
    form = formarchivos()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session["nombrelec"] = form.nombrelec.data
        #print(session["nombrelec"])
        con = sqlite3.connect("base.db") #conecto a la base
        c = con.cursor() #defino el cursor
        c.execute("SELECT Archivo FROM Archivos WHERE Nombre= ?", ([form.nombrelec.data]))
        arch = c.fetchone()

        dire = "C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/"+session["nombrelec"]
        with open(dire, "wb") as output_file:         
            output_file.write(arch[0])
        con.commit()
        con.close()


    return render_template("download.html", form=form)

class formarchivos(FlaskForm):
    con = sqlite3.connect("base.db") #conecto a la base
    c = con.cursor() #defino el cursor
    c.execute("SELECT Nombre FROM Archivos")
    lista = [line[0] for line in c]
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    nombres = [(c,c) for c in lista]
    nombrelec = SelectField('Elija nombre', choices = nombres)
    buscar = SubmitField("Bajar")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

y estos son los templates:
upload.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action = "/" method = "POST" 
  enctype = "multipart/form-data">
  <input type = "file" name = "file" />
  <input type = "submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

dowload.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron d-flex align-items-center"><div class="container text-center">
        <h2>Bajar</h2><br>
        <form class="form-group" method="POST">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ form.nombrelec.label }}<br>{{ form.nombrelec(class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle") }}
            <br>
            <br>
            {{ form.buscar(class="btn btn-success") }}
            </form>

    </div></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

codigo html

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="/xls2" enctype = 'multipart/form-data'>
<div class="form-group" style="background-color:#3498DB">
<label for="file"><h3><strong>Importar datos de excel</strong></h3></label><br>
    <label class="btn btn-file back-in-primary">
<input type="file" id="file" name="excel" class="btn" accept=".xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.csv" 
required>
</label>
<input type="submit" class="btn-lg in-btn-inverse" name="send" value="Enviar">
</div>
</form>
```

Codigo Flask

```
@main.route('/xls2', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def xls2():    
    files=request.files['excel']
    directory='app/static/xls' 
    if files:
        filename = secure_filename(files.filename)
        files.save(os.path.join(directory, filename))
    return render_template('500.html')
```

Puedes hacer lo mismo con cualquier tipo de fichero

Comment: Explica un poco lo que hace cada fragmento de codigo.